# Ionic 4 tabs, failure to compile

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

I am having failures to compile on app.component.ts, park-data.ts, and park-list.page.ts. I am following the national park tabs app in Mobile App Development with Ionic by Griffin. I am having trouble translating it into Ionic 4.

Followed steps in book, have attempted to use new Ionic 4. Worked until I got to the parks tab and providers. Most issues come from park-data.ts. I tried commenting out that pages code to see if I can get it to compile, only throws more errors.

Full code on https://github.com/Blen6035/TabsParksHaberman

```
        resetList(event) {
            this.parkData.getParks().then(theResult => {
                this.parks = theResult;
            })
        }
```

I expect this to compile so I can proceed with styling. Parks tab should sho a list of national parks with search bar. When a park is clicked on more details about the park should open. Currently app will not compile when served.

Comment: let us know the errors , so some one may give you suggestion to solve it

Comment: I have corrected errors in the github above. The app now compiles but the screen is black instead of my tab 1

Comment: I found several typos and missing pieces of code. The code in my git hub is now correct! Not sure how to mark this as solved or delete it.